# ROC Curve and precision recall curve

Tags: machine-learning, roc, auc, precision-recall

What are the underlying assumptions of the ROC curve?

What part of an ROC curve impacts the PR curve more?

[image]

Comment: Read this [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113326/what-is-a-good-auc-for-a-precision-recall-curve) on Cross-Validated discussing ROC-AUC vs. AUC-PR.

Answer (score 2):

ROC Curves summarize the trade-off between the True Positive Rate and False Positive Rate using different probability thresholds.

Precision-Recall curves summarize the trade-off between the True Positive Rate and the Positive predictive value using different probability thresholds.

ROC curves are appropriate when the target class is balanced, whereas Precision-Recall curves are suitable for imbalanced datasets.

Here is a good [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4349800/) for deeper understanding.

Comment: I would also add [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01658) for more info about evaluation metrics on inbalanced datasets